# Lwuit different behaviour on touch screen (arrow keys displayed)

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-button

My lwuit application works fine on my qwerty phone.

However, when I transfer it to a touch screen phone an ugly black keypad comes up along with the application. The keypad consists of 4 arrow keys and 4 keys {A,B,C,D}. This keypad occupied almost 40% of the screen.

I have added drag events so that the user can navigate the app with a stylus.

1) How do I disable the arrow keys from coming up?

I tried setting the VKB to null, but thats not working.

2) I am having some painting issues with the application. I have used a button.flatten property which works fine on my qwerty phone. But on the touch screen , it works sometimes and at other times it does not.

How do i solve these issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For disable the arrow keys from coming up, if you have a nokia phone you must put an attribute in your jad file, Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad. Take a look on this site:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_on-screen_keypad_in_MIDlets_in_S60_5th_Edition_devices

Sorry but I don't understand whats happening in the second issue.